How to change bundle version by Shell in Custom iOS Target Properties in Xcode 13 where Info.plist has been removed?
In the past, we could modify info.plist to auto increase bundle version like:
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :ApplicationProperties:CFBundleVersion 45"

But, since now Info.plist has been removed. So how could we set CFBundleVersion in Custom iOS Target Properties by shell. If it could be solved, we could just change bundle version in scripts for CD.

I believe you can't do that, even with avgtool. You need to:

Set GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE in Build Settings to NO.
Create a new Property List file, copy all the current properties (including CFBundleVersion field), and add it to your project folder.
Config the new Info.plist file path in Build Setting -> Packing -> Info.plist File

Now, you're able to use one of these:
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion 45" Info.plist

agvtool new-version -all "45"

